# I missed Redd on his first visit to my Animal Crossing: New Horizons island. When does he come back?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-horizons

The recent update to Animal Crossing New Horizons added Redd as an occasional NPC.  According to [this guide](https://www.gamesradar.com/au/animal-crossing-new-horizons-art-museum-redd/), the first time he appears, Isabelle announces it.

The problem is, I forgot to talk to him on that day, and he hasn’t come back since.

How long do I have to wait to get him to reappear?

EDIT: To be clear - my understanding is that to have him appear in his boat, you need to buy the initial artwork to open the art gallery in the museum.  I didn't do that.  So now Blathers keeps saying "I'd love you to donate art" but I don't have any art to donate!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

He did eventually return; he still appears on the plaza until you buy from him for the first time / the museum upgrades (not sure what would happen if you buy your first artwork from a friend’s island), but Isabelle doesn’t announce it.  I didn’t record when his initial visit was, but the return was probably around the two week result that others have mentioned.

You seem to only be able to have one of the extra NPCs at a time.  So if you are being visited by Flick, CJ, Leif, Sahara, Label, Gulliver, Wisp, etc that day, I don’t think he appears.  That may well be why it takes so long to reappear.

Comment: That's definitely not 100% right. You can be visited by some NPCs at the same day others are there. For example I got Saharah to sell me Rugs yesterday and in the evening I got a visit of Wisp as well. 
That's maybe because daily NPCs de-spawn at the evening so they make room for an night time NPC to spawn. (Celeste or Wisp)
So yeah you may be only able to have one NPC at a time, but it is not limited to one NPC per day.

Comment: @Roybind93 Wisp and Celeste are not "daily vendor" NPCs.  They are not in the normal rotation of NPCs, they are not there all day (only after 7PM) and are there at the same time as other NPCs.

Answer (score 6):

As with most visiting NPCs he'll likely show up at random. I don't know how much testing they have done, but Gamewith seems to think around every 2 weeks or so:

https://gamewith.net/animal-crossing-new-horizons/article/show/18085

Answer (score 3):

I have had Redd appear the second next day after he initially appeared on my island. 
You can always check if he is there by looking at your map since his trawler does already appear, even if he did not open it for you already. His trawler has a shop symbol located at your islands secret beach.

I'd guess Redd will be like C.J. and Flick. Where one of them appears every 3-5 days on your island.

But maybe he even got his own unique spawn conditions and you can have him, C.J. or Flick and one of the vendors appearing at the town square at the same time.

Comment: Forgot to mention: I think Sahara is occupying the same sort of spot like C.J. and Flick do. I had her visit twice now, and I am waiting pretty long on C.J. at the moment. So every 2 weeks is probably a correct estimate.